Request processing failed: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Entitiy is not mapped
I have a problem with spring mvc project.
But project does't working.
jakarta.servlet.ServletException: Request processing failed: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Employee is not mapped [from Employee]
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1022)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:903)
jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:564)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885)
jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:658)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
Entity class:
package spring_mvc.entity;

import jakarta.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serializable;

@Entity
@Table(name = "employees")
public class Employee  implements Serializable{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "surname")
    private String surname;

    @Column(name = "deaprtment")
    private String deaprtment;

    @Column(name = "salary")
    private int salary;


    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getSurname() {
        return surname;
    }

    public void setSurname(String surname) {
        this.surname = surname;
    }

    public String getDeaprtment() {
        return deaprtment;
    }

    public void setDeaprtment(String deaprtment) {
        this.deaprtment = deaprtment;
    }

    public int getSalary() {
        return salary;
    }

    public void setSalary(int salary) {
        this.salary = salary;
    }

    public Employee() {
    }

    public Employee(Long id, String name, String surname, String deaprtment, int salary) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.surname = surname;
        this.deaprtment = deaprtment;
        this.salary = salary;
    }
}

DaoImpl:
package spring_mvc.dao;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.query.Query;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import spring_mvc.entity.Employee;
import java.util.List;

@Repository
public class EmployeeDaoImpl implements EmployeeDao{

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public List<Employee> getAllEmployees() {
        Session session=sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

        Query<Employee> query=session.createQuery("from Employee",Employee.class); // error points to this part 
        List<Employee> allEmployees= query.getResultList();
        return allEmployees;
    }
}

Controller class:
package spring_mvc;

/* imports */

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class SecondController {

    @Autowired
    private EmployeeDao employeeDao;

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String showAllEmployees(Model model){
        List<Employee> allEmployees=employeeDao.getAllEmployees();           
        model.addAttribute("allemployees",allEmployees);
        return "allEmpsView";

    }
}

applicationContext.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans /* cfgs */>

    <context:component-scan base-package="spring_mvc" />

    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

    <bean
            class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
          destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClass" value="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/my_db?useSSL=false" />
        <property name="user" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory"
          class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="spring_mvc.entity" />
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="current_session_context_class">thread</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager"
          class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />


</beans>

pom.xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.Temirlan.spring.mvc</groupId>
  <artifactId>untitled4</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>untitled4 Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
      <version>6.1.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
      <version>6.1.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
      <version>6.1.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
      <version>6.1.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
      <version>6.1.10</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
      <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
      <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
      <version>8.3.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate.orm</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
      <version>6.2.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
      <version>6.2.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate.orm</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
      <version>6.2.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
      <artifactId>jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
      <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
      <version>1.18.30</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.mchange</groupId>
      <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
      <version>0.9.5.5</version>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>untitled4</finalName>
  </build>
</project>


After launch, it throws the error jakarta.servlet.ServletException: Request processing failed: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Employee is not mapped [from Employee]

Which Spring version are you using? Don't use current_session_context_class ditch that from your configuration, also don't use openSession use getCurrentSession.

LIke @M.Deinum I think this may be version related. jakarta.persistence.* is v17 and your SessionFactory may not be. Can you add the import for SessionFactory to  EmployeeDaoImpl in the posted code.

@JohnWilliams JakartaEE has nothing to do with Java17 or up, you can use JavaEE with Java17 perfectly fine.

@M.Deinum , i have changed openSession   to getCurrentSession . But , then i have another error: jakarta.servlet.ServletException: Request processing failed: org.hibernate.HibernateException: No CurrentSessionContext configured!

@JohnWilliams , Added imports to EmployeeDaoImpl

For starters your dependencies are a mess. You are mixing Spring 6.1.8 and 6.1.10, don't mix jars from different versions. Your hibernate is also mixing 5.4.26, 6.0.0.CR and 6.5.2. So start by fixing the dependencies.

@M.Deinum ,Thanks for the advice, I corrected the dependencies in the file and brought them into one version. But same error :
jakarta.servlet.ServletException: Request processing failed: org.hibernate.HibernateException: No CurrentSessionContext configured

Do you have a hibernate.cfg.xml or hibernate.properties somewhere? If so remove it.

@M.Deinum , no , there is no hibernate.cfg.xml or hibernate.properties files . Only applicationContext.xml and web.xml .

Why did you change your hibernate-validator? That version was correct, also you don't need hibernate-c3po and I would suggest using HikariCP instead of C3PO.
